# Is there any way to use Android CameraX API with minimum SDK less than 21?

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-camerax

Is it possible to use AndroidX CameraX API on minimum SDK version less than 21?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not.  As noted in the [official CameraX overview](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax), it only has backward compatibility to Android 5.0 (API level 21).

This page also hints at the reason for this: It makes use of the [`camera2` API, which was added in API level 21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary).  Previously, there was a different (and less powerful) camera API, so adding full backward compatibility would probably be impossible, and even partial backward compatibility would be non-trivial.